# Array of ArrayList with Integers filled with combinations

Tags: java, arrays, recursion, arraylist

Suppose this, I obtain an array of Integer Wraps Objects...

```
Integer[] p = new Integer[]{7, 5, 3, 2};  //Variable Length
```

Now, I want create an Array of ArrayList with next respective values.

```
2
3
3, 2
5
5, 2
5, 3
5, 3, 2
7
7, 2
7, 3
7, 3, 2
7, 5
7, 5, 2
7, 5, 3, 2
7, 5, 3, 2
```

**What code helps me to create an array with value shown before?**

In this code I tried generate:

```
  public static void generateTable(int index, int[] current, int[] values) {
    if(index == values.length) {
      for(int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
        System.out.print((current[i]) + " ");
      }
      System.out.println();
    } else {
        current[index] = 0;
        generateTable(index + 1, current, values);
        current[index] = values[index];
        generateTable(index + 1, current, values);
    }
  }
```

This code only show the combination I want to extract only the before combinations (Except Zero values).

```
0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 2 
0 0 3 0 
0 0 3 2 
0 5 0 0 
0 5 0 2 
0 5 3 0 
0 5 3 2 
7 0 0 0 
7 0 0 2 
7 0 3 0 
7 0 3 2 
7 5 0 0 
7 5 0 2 
7 5 3 0 
7 5 3 2
```

I test with this code:

```
java.util.List<Integer>[] arr = new ArrayList[p.length];
for( int i = 0; i < p.length; i++) {
  arr[i] = new ArrayList();
  for (int j = 0; j <= i; j++) {
    arr[i].add(p[j]);
  }
  System.out.println(arr[i]);
}
```

The output for before code is not working properly, is not recursive and doesn't show the omitted value like `[5, 3, 2]` or `[7, 5, 2]` , etc!

```
[7]
[7, 5]
[7, 5, 3]
[7, 5, 3, 2]
```

Comment: why is there new keyword two times?

Comment: I have downvoted this question because it appears to be a zero-effort requirements dump.  If you can [edit] your question to show us a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your attempt, or to clarify *precisely* where you are having difficulty, this downvote may be retracted.

Comment: @JoeC I have problem with recursion, how put the `ArrayList[]` into `generateTable` method. If you can help me, Will be valuable for me.

Comment: @BrijRajKishore `List<Integer>[] arr = new ArrayList[p.length];` for Declaring Array of ArrayList.
Initializing an ArrayList `arr[i] = new ArrayList();`

Answer (score 1):

Instead of directly converting arrays into List. When you do that 0s will also be picked up and placed in your list. Iterate through each index of your array, find only non-zero elements and put them into your list. Can this help?

Comment: Hi, Sorry, Can you help me with the code...
Have you some name for this method?